# react-image-crop image rotation issue only in portrait mode of iPhone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using [react-image-crop](https://github.com/DominicTobias/react-image-crop) library to get users to select a picture and crop it.

The library works beautifully until you are on an iPhone. Taking a portrait (aka vertical) picture places the image in the correct rotation while cropping on canvas but on complete is in the wrong direction.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/72py4jlll6) from the creator himself.

**ISSUE**
Below is an image where on top, the cropping section, the image is in correct orientation, but the output image on the bottom is in the wrong direction.

[image: Sample issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to load an additional library:

```
npm i blueimp-load-image --S
```

Load it into your page

```
import loadImage from "blueimp-load-image/js";
```

And instead of using the fileReader, use the library like so:

```
  onSelectFile = e => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      loadImage(
        e.target.files[0],
        img => {
          var base64data = img.toDataURL(`image/jpeg`);
          this.setState({ src: base64data });
        },
        { orientation: true, canvas: true }
      );

      // const reader = new FileReader();
      // reader.addEventListener('load', () =>
      //   this.setState({ src: reader.result })
      // );
      // reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };
```

Here is a working example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-crop-demo-with-classes-wg4fc?file=/src/index.js:191-209)

Comment: I get the error: "img.toDataURL is not a function", trying to find a solution...

Comment: You didn't add "canvas: true" in the option of loadImage